# Gatsby routing issue for 404 pages with language keys

Tags: routes, gatsby

I am building a blog with multiple languages support. URLs contain language keys, e.g. `/en/blog`. I ran into an issue with localizing 404 pages. What's described here https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-prefixed-404-pages-for-different-languages/ works well for all routes but the home page. The home page has the following URL `www.test.com/en`, and it ends up with 404 page because of this regex `/^\/[a-z]{2}\/404\/$/`
I tried to pass in a regex  `^\/?[a-z]{2}\/.+` to match all routes but the `/en` one but the `matchPath` does not seem to except regex.

Pages are ranked under the hood; however, it seems that `/en` and `/en/does-not-exist` are treated the same, or the latter takes precedence over the former.

I wonder if someone faced this issue before and maybe there was a workaround.

For now, I have a generic 404 and also separate 404 pages for all available languages. In the generic 404, I want to redirect to the language-specific 404 version. It adds complexity which I'd like to avoid.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is a know `everything in match-paths.json` issue. https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/19228

For now my workaround is using redirects based on language key.

I have a default 404 page and language specific 404 pages, e.g. `/en/404`.
Inside the default 404 page I simply redirect lie so:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { navigate } from 'gatsby'

// Assuming the urls are structured this way /en/blog/does-not-exist
const getLanguage = (location) => location.pathname.split('/')[1]

const NotFoundPage = ({ location }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    navigate(`/${getLanguage(location)}/404`, { replace: false })
  }, []);

  return null
}

export default NotFoundPage
```

Not the best solution but it does the job for now. Will post an update once I have a better solution.